# How to insert the hidden field data into database using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi While login into the site iam getting the username in hidden field while filling the form after login i need to insert the username in database.But iam getting The error as

Notice: Undefined index: email

Here is my code

index.php

```
<?php  
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
if($username) 
{ 
?>
<h3> Welcome <?php echo $username; ?></h3>
<?php 
}  
else 
{ 
echo "no"; 
} 
?> 
<body>       
    <input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $username; ?>" name='email'>        
    <input type="button" value="Logout" id="logout" onClick="document.location.href='login.php'" />    
    <form method="post" action="details.php" id="myform">            
        <ul class="tab-content">
                <li class="tab-pane active" id="salary">                
                            <h3>Details</h3>
                            <table style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black;">
                            <tr class="spaces">
                              <th>User Name</th></tr>
                              <tr>
                              <td><input type="text" name="user_name" value="" required /></td>
                              </tr>
```

details.php

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("accountant", $connection);
$email=$_POST['email'];
$name=$_POST['user_name'];
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_details(email,user_name)values('$email','$name')");
```

Can anyone help me this thanks in advance

While filling this form i need to insert the hidden field value also in database

Comment: First of all you need to place the hidden input field inside the Form. Then the value will be sent together with other data. And from there you can access the value as other values inside the form. (which you have already done as i can see).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting that field in form tag and you done.

```
<?php
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    if($username){?>
        <h3> Welcome <?php echo $username; ?></h3>
    <?php } else {
        echo "no";
    }
?>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Logout" id="logout" onClick="document.location.href='login.php'" />
    <form method="post" action="details.php" id="myform">
        <input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $username; ?>" name='email'>
        <ul class="tab-content">
            <li class="tab-pane active" id="salary">
                <h3>Details</h3>
                <table style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black;">
                    <tr class="spaces">
                        <th>User Name</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="user_name" value="" required />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks..If my answer was helpful then accept it by clicking right marker and give up vote. This is the best way to appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You hidden field must be inside your form . Otherwise its value not submit  form action and you will get Undefined Notice

```
<form method="post" action="details.php" id="myform"> 
 <input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $username; ?>" name='email'>      

--- rest code---

 <input type="button" value="Logout" id="logout" onClick="document.location.href='login.php'" />  

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting Undefined Index notice because you are not using your hidden input inside the `<form></form>`

```
<input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $username; ?>" name='email'>
```

Keep in mind either filed hidden or visible you will define it inside the `<form></form>` otherwise you will get the Notices.

**Side Note:**

Please use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` extension, because `mysql_*` is deprecated and not available in PHP 7.

One more issue, your submit button also out side the `<form>` but it will work because you are using `onclick()` event, but its not good practice.

Your code is open for **SQL Injection**, you need to prevent with SQL Injection.

One last thing, i hope you are using `session_start()` on top in your file for getting `$_SESSION['username'];` in your original code, please recheck.

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```
<?php  
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
if($username) 
{ 
?>
<h3> Welcome <?php echo $username; ?></h3>
<?php 
}  
else 
{ 
echo "no"; 
} 
?> 
<body>       

<input type="button" value="Logout" id="logout" onClick="document.location.href='login.php'" />    
<form method="post" action="details.php" id="myform">            
    <ul class="tab-content">
            <li class="tab-pane active" id="salary">
  <input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $username; ?>" name='email'>                 
                        <h3>Details</h3>
                        <table style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black;">
                        <tr class="spaces">
                          <th>User Name</th></tr>
                          <tr>
                          <td><input type="text" name="user_name" value="" required /></td>
                          </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  session_start();
  // you have to start the session in order to work with php session.  
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> <form method="post" action="details.php" id="myform">   <input
> type='hidden' value="<?php echo $username; ?>" name='email'>      
> 
>  <input type="button" value="Logout" id="logout"
> onClick="document.location.href='login.php'" />  
> 
> </form>
```

hidden type always contain hidden value