# How to display a certain page only when the user is logged in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am creating an admin panel in core PHP without login into the admin panel I am able to see the menus inside the admin panel.Can anyone help me regarding this.
here is my code.

Blogs.php

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("accountant", $connection);
$name=$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
$type=$_FILES["myfile"]["type"];
$size=$_FILES["myfile"]["size"];
$temp=$_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"];
$error=$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
if($error>0)
    die("error while uploading");
else
{
    if($type == "image/png" || $type == "image/jpeg" ||$type == "image/jpg" ||  $type == "image/svg" || $size >2000000)
    {       
        move_uploaded_file($temp,"upload/".$name);
        echo "upload complete";
    }
    else
    {
        die("Format not allowed or file size too big!");
    }
}
```

blog.php(This is my view)

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['logged_in']){
session_destroy();
header("Location: login.php");
}
?>

<form method="POST" action="blogs.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
<label for="image">IMAGE</label>
<input type="file" name="image">
</div>
</form>
```

login.php

```
<?php
session_start()
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Form</title>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="login_model.php">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="message">
        <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION["message"]))
        {
            echo"Registration Successful";
            unset($_SESSION["message"]);
    }    
   if(isset($_SESSION["messagefail"]))
   {
    echo"You entered wrong cradentials...Try Again here";
    unset($_SESSION["messagefail"]);
   }
if (isset($_SESSION['logout'])) {
echo "Logout Successful";
session_destroy();
} 
?>
</div>
        <h1 align="center"> ADMIN Login Page </h1>
    <table align="center" border="1">
        <tr>   
            <td> User Name : <input type="text" name="admin_email" id="admin_email" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Password    :  <input name="admin_password" type="password" id="admin_password" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit"/>
        </tr>            
    </table>        
</div>
</form>
```

login_model.php

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("accountant", $connection);
$name = $_POST["admin_email"];
$password = $_POST["admin_password"];
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
$query = "SELECT * FROM admin_login where admin_email= '$name' AND admin_password= '$password' ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($rows>0){
session_start();
header("Location:blog.php");
}   
else
{
echo "Invalid Username or Password";    
}   
}
?>
```

Without login into admin panel if I give direct URL I can view the page.First I should login into admin panel later only I should access this section.Can anyone help me this .Thanks in advance.

Comment: resembles your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177218/how-to-insert-the-hidden-field-data-into-database-using-php - from a given/accepted answer; so what's the problem here? I don't see anything related to what you want to do.

Comment: Without loggin if i give direct url as localhost/accounting/admin/blog.php then it is opening that particular page but it should show only when the user is logged in or else it should redirect to login page.

Comment: you have no related code here. Ask the guy below who gave you an answer.

Comment: In that question which you posted iam not able to insert the hidden field id in database that has been solved.

Comment: Actually i dont know iam asking how can i do that one

Comment: the answer accepted contains `$username = $_SESSION['username'];
    if($username){?>
        <h3> Welcome <?php echo $username; ?></h3>`, so work on that.

Comment: Your explanation is not at all related to your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Do Like This:
On every Page In the starting of the Code you have to check the session .
The Session will be set by successful login only.
If the session is not found redirect it to LOGIN Page.
Sample Code On blog.php

```
<?php 
 If(!isset($_SESSION['YOUR_SESSION_Variable']))
{
  header('Location: login.php');
 }?>
```

Assuming your login file is "login.php" at the same location.

Comment: Thank you its working for url but if i try to login then iam not able to login with correct credentials also.

Comment: @user5751258 you should start a session `session_start();`

Comment: It will just check that user's session is active or not,if not active then it will redirect it to Login page.

Comment: but iam not able to login with correct credentials also

Comment: @SanzeebAryal i have started session

Comment: Can you show your login.php page's code?

Comment: Where have you added that `session_start();`?@KetanSolanki

Comment: @KetanSolanki i have updated my login.php code can you please check it

Comment: @user5751258 try with adding session_start(); in the satrting of the code in the blog.php. I may have missed it.

Comment: @KetanSolanki i have updated the code with session_start but iam not able to login with correct credentials also.

Comment: okay it was just to clear the doubt of @SanzeebAryal . Now it's a wild guess that there would be a problem in "login_model.php".

Comment: @KetanSolanki i have updated my login_model.php code at above

Comment: Hi pLease can anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());

$db = mysql_select_db("accountant", $connection);

$name = $_POST["admin_email"];

$password = $_POST["admin_password"];

if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){

$query = "SELECT * FROM admin_login where admin_email= '$name' AND admin_password= '$password' ";

$result = mysql_query($query);

$rows=mysql_num_rows($result);

//Change this condition also like :
if($rows==1){

session_start();

// Set Your Session Variable Here like following:

$_SESSION['userId'] = "Your User Id From The Query";

header("Location:blog.php");

}   
else

{

echo "Invalid Username or Password";    

}   
}
?>
```